# How to approach a "multi-search" box (in CakePHP)?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

My hobby project starts to take form, but there's one thing I'm trying to figure out: multi-search box.

Think of Facebook's search feature: when you start typing, the search box searches for friends, company pages, games, groups and so on, with suggestions of the best guesses. In the context of my site, there's multiple tables I want the search to work on simultaneously while giving the best suggestions of each table.

How would such a feature be approached?

Comment: This isn't cakephp specific. You query a search index (either a dedicated tool such as elastic sesrch, or it you want a very simple but much less efficient solution, a single table which includes a table and table_id field).

Answer (score 0):

Join all the table... search by 'OR'

Comment: Isn't that awfully inefficient if there's tens of tables and hundreds of thousands of entries?

Comment: Well, Facebook has tens of tables and hundreds of thousands of entries... Its all depends on how you designed your database.

Comment: And I can tell you, facebook does not query every item in the database. Now you are giving him an answer which is really bad practice. If you do your query, with a few users you get so many inefficient database querys... A better way should be to cache some key items, so you do not have to query the DB 24/7. Or make 1 single "search" table with some key words linked to items.

Comment: @WvanRij, I understand what you mean. Thank you, at least someone reply to that answer. I know its not a efficient way to do that. He told that its his hobby project and i think it may give him a basic idea. Its not possible to tell here how facebook works in this page while I really know a few about the facebook structure. I appreciate if you place a good answer here. Other may get help. Thank you.